# TShape - drawing issue on Paint event

Tags: windows, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm stuck in a class derived from `TShape`.

In the `Paint` method, I use the `Canvas` to draw a rectangle. In the Form, I have a `TTrackBar` that allows to change `Left` and `Top` coordinates of the `TShape`.

It does not matter what values I set to the `Left` and `Top` using the `TTrackBar`, the rectangle does not move accordingly. Instead, when I set those values via code, the rectangle appears in the correct position.

I'm coding a FireMonkey app with Delphi 10.1 Berlin on Windows 10.

```
unit frmShapeStudy;

interface

type
  tMy_Shape = class (tShape)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create (aOwner: tComponent); override;
    procedure   Draw;
  end;

  tformShapeStudy = class (tForm)
     trkBarLeft: TTrackBar;
     trkBarTop: TTrackBar;
    procedure FormCreate     (Sender: tObject);
    procedure TrackBarChange (Sender: tObject);
  end;

var
  formShapeStudy: tformShapeStudy;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

var
  My_Shape    : tMy_Shape;
  lvShapeRect : tRectF   ;

procedure tformShapeStudy.FormCreate (Sender: tObject);
begin
  My_Shape := tMy_Shape.Create (Self);
  with My_Shape do begin
     Parent := Self;
     TrackBarChange (Self);
  end;
end;

procedure tformShapeStudy.TrackBarChange (Sender: TObject);
begin
  My_Shape.Draw;
end; 

constructor tMy_Shape.Create (aOwner: tComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  with lvShapeRect do begin
         Left   := Self.Left;
         Top    := Self.Top ;
         Height :=  20;
         Width  :=  20;
  end;
end;

procedure tBS_Shape.Draw;
begin
  l := formShapeStudy.trkBarLeft.Value;
  t := formShapeStudy.trkBarTop .Value;
  {`Left & Top` are set with `l & t` or with `120 & 150` 
  and tested separately, by commenting the propper code lines}
  lvShapeRect.Left   := l;    // this does no work
  lvShapeRect.Top    := t;    // this does no work
  lvShapeRect.Left   := 120;  // this works
  lvShapeRect.Top    := 150;  // this works
  Repaint;
end;

procedure tMy_Shape.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  with Canvas do begin
       Fill  .Color := tAlphaColorRec.Aqua;
       Stroke.Color := tAlphaColorRec.Blue;
       BeginScene;
       FillRect (lvShapeRect, 0, 0, Allcorners, 1, tCornerType.Bevel);
       DrawRect (lvShapeRect, 0, 0, Allcorners, 1, tCornerType.Bevel);
       EndScene;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: The `ShapeRect` property is read-only, you can't modify it. Every time you access it, a temp `TRectF` is returned. Your code is modifying those temp `TRectF`s, which are not assigned back to the `TShape`. That is why the rectangle does not move.

Comment: @Remy. In case you didn't notice, `ShapeRect` is a local variable declared in the begining of the implementation section. I think that this declaration has precedence over the `ShapeRect` property of `tShape`. Anyway, the code above is just an excerpt of the real code, in wich that variable is declared as `lvShapeRect` (`lv` meaning `local variable`), hence it does not colide with the `ShapeRect` property. I'm renaming that declaration to `lvShapeRect`.

Comment: can you print the value of l and t ?

Comment: @loki - Sorry I didn't understand what you mean. You want to know the values, or you ask me if I can print those values on my printer?

Comment: no, jus to know theses values ... because if in you sample theses value equal 120 and 150 and not work then you have a problem

Comment: @Ioki. The values are not equal to 120 and 150. They come from a TrackBar, whose values varies from -199 to +199.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Folks! Is the old habit of using `Left` & `Top` instead of `Position.X` & `Position.Y`. I agree with the new `Position` way to set `Left` & `Top`, but it doesn't make sense that Embarcadero still makes available this properties, but they do nothing in terms of setting `Left` & `Top` of the control. Saying it in other words, since those old properties are still available, they should set the `Left` & `Top` properties same as `Position.X` & `Position.Y`, otherwise it leads to this kind of mistake, where you sware you are setting `Left` & `Top`, but the control does not move.

The correct way to set `Left` & `Top` is:

```
Position.X := aLeft;
Position.Y := aTop;
```

unless Embarcadero changes the behavior of `Left` & `Top` properties (wich is very unlikely).